# How to find and replace multiple values in Excel at the same time?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very large Excel sheet with 1000's of values that contain over 200 different countries, I want to change each country to either Zone 1, Zone 2, Zone 3 ... to Zone 10 etc.  I also want to be able to enter Countries in the future, into this sheet, and have them automatically change to the zone that I have specified.

For example,  'Jersey' would become 'Zone 1' and 'Monaco' would become 'Zone 1' also, whereas 'Norway' would become 'Zone 3'.

I have a large table with the Countries and the Zones to the specific country:  Big list with over 200 counties below:

```
Jersey         Zone 1
Monaco         Zone 1
San Marino     Zone 1
Albania        Zone 2
Greenland      Zone 2
Norway         Zone 3
etc etc...     ...
               Zone 10
```

Section of list I want converted:

```
Jersey
Monaco
San Marino
Albania
Greenland
Norway
UK
USA
Ireland
France
Spain
```

My attempted code for this so far (Which does nothing) is to try and Substitute the values with other values that are in the columns above, here G3:G208 is the Countries above, and H3:H208 is the zones.  I want this to affect the whole sheet, all countries must become the zone specified, and future entries will change to the specified Zone automatically.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1:F999,INDEX(G3:G208,I4:N1003),INDEX(H3:H208,,I4:N1003))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like this can be solved by V-Lookup formula https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function

Comment: @TanmayGawankar Not really. VLOOKUP could be used to put the zone in a cell next to the cell containing the country. What is sounds like the OP wants is for the cell containing the country to be overwritten with the Zone. I don't think this is possible without a macro.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using INDEX/MATCH, rather than a VLOOKUP.
It is much quicker when dealing with a large number of formulas. Also, although your requirements are very basic, INDEX/MATCH is much more versatile, so would be useful in more complex situations.

[image]

```
=IFNA(
    INDEX($E$3:$E$10,MATCH($A3,$D$3:$D$10,0)),
    "Not Found"
)
```

EDIT: I miss understood what the OP wanted...

Sorry. I think what you actually want is the original data to be overwritten. So the cell containing "Jersey", changes to contain "Zone 1" instead.
I don't think this is possible without a VBA macro.

You could create a separate sheet which would act as a read only report. It would be identical to the original "input" sheet, except that it changes the cells containing countries to zones.